# Difference between auto_now_add and timezone.now as default value

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-database

What is the difference between `auto_now_add` and `timezone.now` (as default value) for models in Django?
Example:

```py
create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

and

```py
create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

?

**UPD.** I'm talking about the case when I always not overriding default value.

Answer (score 11):

> `default` supplies a default value for when an instance is being saved without a value for the field, but still implies that the field is user-editable, so someone could input a value for the field.
>
> `auto_now` and `auto_now_add` imply the field is not user-editable and must *always* get set to this value.

Someone posted this [on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/55d3ym/djangs_auto_now_addtrue_vs_custom/).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Django does the same `timezone.now()` [under the hood](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L1186), on `pre_save`:

```py
def pre_save(self, model_instance, add):
    if self.auto_now or (self.auto_now_add and add):
        value = timezone.now()
        setattr(model_instance, self.attname, value)
        return value
    else:
        return super(DateTimeField, self).pre_save(model_instance, add)
```

The only difference is the moment when python will call `timezone.now()`, but that should be nano-seconds difference.

Answer (score -1):

Explanation:

**auto_now_add=True** will create date on save model

**default=timezone.now** will be default date with timezone and you must enter date with timezone

Link to explanation: [DateModel](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/datefield-django-models/)

Comment: I think both will be with TZ. Or not? And why `must enter date`, I can always use default value?

Comment: You don't have blank=True, null=True on that field so it can't be bypassed by default. Django will save datetime with default timezone.now in every save method.